# load a gif image while the deleting an image via ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, django-templates

I have a page where user upload images. each image is assigned a delete button. I'm trying to implement a way where when a clicks delete button under the image, that specific delete button dissapear and a gif image is loaded when the ajax request is loading, and the gif image should dissapear once the refresh is completed.
Here is what am trying but it's not working.

```
$(function(){
    $('.delete-img-btn').live('click', function() {
        //asign the image id from the button attribute 'img-id'
        var id= $(this).attr('img-id');
        //The data to be send via ajax the server will recieve 2 POST variables ie. 'action' and 'id'(which is the img id)
        var data={
            'action':'/admin/image-uploader/',
                'pk':id,
           'success':refreshUploadedImages
        };

        $('.inner').empty();
        $('.inner').append('<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}admin/img/admin/ajax-loader.gif" id="spinner">');
        //inherit parent element (our delete button)
        $(this).ajaxStart(function() {
            $('#spinner').show();
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
            $('#spinner').hide();
        });
        $.post("/admin/image-uploader/delete/"+id ,function(data){
            refreshUploadedImages()
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`... show the spinner before `$.post` and hide it after `$.post` completes (callback function).

```
$('.inner').empty();
$('.inner').append('<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}admin/img/admin/ajax-loader.gif" id="spinner">');  //show here
$.post("/admin/image-uploader/delete/"+id ,function(data){
    $('#spinner').hide();  //hide here
    refreshUploadedImages()
});
```

Comment: The It's all the buttons and not even loading the gif. I want it to hide only the button under the image.. and load the gif..

Comment: can you post your html too.. so that i can see the structure and modiify likewise coz its hard to answer your question assuming html by myself.. :)